# Not equal operator in pyspark giving wrong results

Tags: pyspark

I am looking for this particular record in an array and it find the rows as below:

```
xarr.filter(xarr["orderid"] == 27952740).count()
```

This gives 67,272 rows which is the right answer.

Then I do this. Assign all Non-zero values to another array:

```
xarr2 = xarr.filter(xarr["orderid"] != 0)
```

Now in the resulting array xarr2, I am trying to locate the record as follows:

```
xarr2.filter(xarr2["orderid"] == 27952740).count()
```

This one returns zero records. Why is this behavior? Any idea?

Comment: A little light on details here. What does `xarr2.count()` show? What about `xarr.where(xarr["orderid"] != 0).where(xarr["orderid"] == 27952740).count()`? Please try to break this down into a [mcve].

Comment: thats another thing. the no of records with != 0 and == 0 do not match with the total in the master array.

Comment: xarr.count() -- 129261427

Comment: xarr.where(xarr["orderid"] != 0).where(xarr["orderid"] == 27952740).count() #returns 0

Answer (score 1):

The data type of orderid is String. Changing `!= 0`to `!= '0'` gave the correct results.